# What is the point of the textarget parameter for glFramebufferTexture?

Tags: opengl

According to http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glFramebufferTexture.xml, a call to `glFramebufferTexture` should look similar to:

`glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId, 0);`

If the API already knows the `textureId` why does it need to know the target (`GL_TEXTURE_2D`) too? Does this mean that the texture should be bound before this call? i.e. do I need to call:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

Or will `glFramebufferTexture2D` handle everything?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's there because of stupidity.

See, the way you attach a [face of a cubemap](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Cubemap_Texture) to an FBO is to use one of the cubemap face texture targets. So if you want to attach the +X face of a cubemap, you use the `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X​` target. The texture's bind target (if you were binding it) would be `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP`, but that's *not* what you pass to `textarget` when you want to attach a face to an FBO.

This is stupid because OpenGL also provides the [`glFramebufferTextureLayer`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glFramebufferTextureLayer) function, which doesn't take a `textarget` parameter. It correctly identifies the texture's type from just the object. It works on 3D texture, 1D and 2D arrays, and even [cubemap array textures](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Cubemap_Texture#Cubemap_array_textures). But *it does not work* on non-array cubemaps; you still have to use the silly `glFramebufferTexture2D` with it's silly `textarget` parameter.

By all rights, the only functions you should use are `glFramebufferTextureLayer` and `glFramebufferTexture`. But because of how `glFramebufferTextureLayer` doesn't work on non-array cubemap faces, you have to use `glFramebufferTexture2D` for faces of a non-array cubemap.

---

Thanks to [ARB_direct_state_access](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/direct_state_access.txt) (and therefore OpenGL 4.5), this idiocy no longer applies. `glFramebufferTextureLayer` may now be used on non-array cubemap faces, so now there is no point to any of the dimension-based `FramebufferTexture` functions. And therefore, no point to `textarget`.

Comment: So are you saying I should stop using `glFramebufferTexture2D` and start using `glFramebufferTextureLayer` instead? And I don't need to worry about binding the texture before and after the calls?

Comment: @MarkIngram: I changed the last sentence to make it more clear. And my explanation of why the target is there should make it clear that you don't need to bind the texture; I have no idea how you even got that idea.

Comment: Thanks Nicol, I'm using a texture as the output of a GPGPU operation, so won't be dealing with cubemaps.
I got the idea from some sample Apple code, but it might have been that they just didn't unbind the texture when they were done with it.

Comment: You can also use `glTextureView` + `glFramebufferTexture` (just create the original texture storage using `glTexStorage*`) from GL 4.3  instead of `glFramebufferTexture2D` or `glFramebufferTextureLayer` to bind a single layer of a texture to a framebuffer.